# How to get the pods from the namespaces with a particular label?

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, kubernetes-pod

It is possible to get all the pods on the cluster:

```
kubectl get pod --all-namespaces -o wide
```

It is also possible to get all pods on the cluster with a specific label:

```
kubectl get pod --all-namespaces -o wide --selector some.specific.pod.label
```

It is even possible to get all pods on the specific node of the cluster:

```
kubectl get pods --all-namespaces -o wide --field-selector spec.nodeName=<node>
```

The question is, how to get all pods from the namespaces with a particular label?

e.g. `kubectl get pod --namespace-label some.specific.namespace.label -o wide` (pseudocode)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One cannot do that operation in one shot, because labels on `Namespace` objects are not propagated down upon their child objects. Since `kubectl` is merely doing a `GET` on `/api/v1/whatevers` there is no obvious way to make a REST request to two endpoints at once and join them together.

You'll want either a `for` loop in shell, or to use one of the many API client bindings to create a program that does the `Namespace` fetch, then a `Pod` fetch for those matching `Namespaces`; for example:

```sh
for n in $(kubectl get ns --selector some.specific.namespace.label -o name); do
    # it's possible kubectl -n will accept the "namespace/foo" output of -o name
    # or one can even -o go-template='{{ range .items }}{{ .metadata.name }} {{ end }}'
    n=${n##namespace/}
    kubectl -n "$n" get pods -o wide
done
```

Comment: I edited your answer because there was an error on it. Changed from `n=${##namespace/}` to `n=${n##namespace/}`. I tested on my cluster and now it's working as expected. Great solution!